Nuxt: Excluding all routes with query params in sitemap
I've been trying to exclude all routes that have query params in sitemap. However, the sitemap still has routes with query params in it. Does anyone know the correct pattern for this scenario?
sitemap: {
  hostname: process.env.BASE_URI,
  gzip: true,
  routes: routes,
  exclude: [
    '*?*', // Exclude all routes with query params
  ]
}


Do you use this module? I asked your question in this discussion.

I use this one, not sure whether it's the same library with what you referred?
https://nuxt.com/modules/sitemap
I've tried to exclude urls with a trailing slash (**/) and it works. I just don't get the pattern for query params correctly. Let me know if you know the correct pattern or a reason why the pattern I provided for the query params doesn't work.

That's a different name but it's still the same maintainer + same docs haha. I think that it should support regex syntax? Hence if we take this, http://example.com/foo?yolo=icecream, the following regex /\?.+=.*/ detects the ?yolo=icecream part of it, and hence could be excluded from the site-mapping. But there are maybe other ways to exclude this. Let's see if we have an answer to the Github discussion. Here's the regex part to fiddle with it: https://regex101.com/r/ZFboFF/1
